# How to auto expand json view in Firefox Quantum Developer Edition?

Tags: json, firefox, firefox-quantum

As title.

For example, when i go to https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments, the json array is like this

[image]

How can I make it all automatically expanded? So that I can view everything at once instead of expanding it 1 by 1. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Open the page via view source. It will show everything and expanded.

e.g. view-source:https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments